# How to realize the same combination of pan/swipe effect as in navigating between homescreens on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, ios5, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

On the iPhone you can switch between different home screens in three different ways.

1. You can swipe to the left or to the right and the next respectively next screen will be animated in.
2. You touch the screen and without lifting the finger you drag the screen to the right or to the left. After passing critical point (which is a distance more then halve the screen) the next homescreen is animated in when you lift your finger.
3. You touch the screen and without lifting the finger you drag the screen a little, if you want you can stop dragging but still don't left the finger. And you can accelerate to the left or right on a relatively short distance and it will animate to the respective screen to the left or right.

If we mutual exclusively look at the points 1 and 2, we find them trivial to implement. It's just a `UISwipeGuestureRecognizer` for point 1. and a `UIPanGuestureRecognizer`for 2.

Combining 1 and 2 them seems somehow not so trivial, since the swiping seems to dominate (I tried to combine them with `- (void)requireGestureRecognizerToFail:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer`). To trigger the pan I had to lay my finger on the screen and drag very very soft to not trigger the swipe.

Not to speak of point three as an addition. This seems totally out of order for my state of knowledge.

Any advice around here? Thank you very much in advance. If more information is needed to solve this question I will gladly deliver it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The home screen is just an `UIScrollView` with `UIPageControl`
It's that easy :)

Example :

```
// MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *_scrollView;
    UIPageControl *_pageControl;
}

// MyViewController.m
// in your viewDidLoad method
int numberOfPages = 3;
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                                 self.view.frame.size.height)];
 [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(numberOfPages*_scrollView.frame.size.width, _scrollView.frame.size.height)];
 [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
 [_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
 [_scrollView setDelegate:self];
 [self.view addSubview:_scrollView];

 _pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, _scrollView.frame.size.height-30, _scrollView.frame.size.width, 20)];
 [_pageControl setNumberOfPages:numberOfPages];
 [_pageControl setCurrentPage:0];
 [self.view addSubview:_pageControl];

for (int i=0; i<numberOfPages; i++) {
   CGRect frame = _scrollView.frame;
   frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * i;
   frame.origin.y = 0;
   UIView *view = [UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
   //Setup your view     
   [_scrollView addSubview:view];
}
```

If you want to execute specific method regarding current view displayed, use the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method (for example to load content from database)

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender {
    CGFloat pageWidth = _scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((_scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    _pageControl.currentPage = page;

    //do whatever you want..
}
```

It's just an example to show you how you could do. If you're using database or if each view is different you should proceed differently to setup your views or retrieve data but the logic would be the same...

Comment: First of all thanks, for your quick reply. I should have added more information to the question. Is this behavior realizable without using UIPageControl? My Views do present text data from a database. And panning/Swiping to the right/left shall induce the next/last data text. So it is not really a Page but one of thousands views through which the user can browse. The Views are reused - I actually have only three UIViews. One on the left one on the right and one visual in middle.

Comment: That's it, you can do that with `UIScrollView` + `UIPageControl`. I'm going to edit my answer to show you an example.

Comment: There are some good examples in the WWDC 2010 and 2011 videos on scroll views as well, and I think in 2012 they might have updated the demo to use a collection view, which is definitely the way to go if you can require iOS 6.

Comment: Thank you, @ZevEisenberg. Would be so kind to provide a link, if you have one at hand? My Application must run on ios5 AND ios6, so unfortunately I can't only rely on features of ios6.

Answer (score 1):

[WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/)

- look at Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views

[WWDC 2011 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

- check out Advanced Scroll View Techniques